# Cassandra Inconsistent

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax

We are running a cassandra cluster with 3 nodes and a replication factor of 2.

Our nodejs server is the only place this cluster is queried from.

We are using the datastax node.js driver to create a client as follows:

```
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: [<contact point>], keyspace: 'test_keyspace', queryOptions: {consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.two}});
```

My understanding is this consistency parameter being set to two should make our reads/writes consistent so long as we wait for a response before proceeding to the next query, but this is not happening.

Is it true the above should guarantee consistency if we wait for a response before requesting the data?

Is there anywhere else where there might be parameters set that might cause inconsistent queries?

cassandra v2.2.4
nodejs driver version v3.0.0

Edit - add example of what I am doing:

Tables:

test_keyspace.users(id uuid, username text, join_date timestamp, PRIMARY KEY(id))

test_keyspace.username(username text, uuid id, PRIMARY KEY(username, id))

On create user:

1) Check username is not taken

```
        var query = "SELECT * FROM test_keyspace.username WHERE username=?";
        db.execute(query, [username], function(err, result){
            if(err){
                //fail check - api responds with internal server error
            } else {
                if(result.rows.length == 0){
                //pass check, proceeed to #2
                } else {
                //fail check, username taken, respond with error
                }
            }
        });
```

2) Creates user

```
var queries = [
    {
        query: "INSERT INTO test_keyspace.users (id, username, join_date) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
        params: [userid, username, date]
    },
    {
        query: "INSERT INTO test_keyspace.username(id, username) VALUES(?, ?)",
        params: [userid, username]
    }
]

db.batch(queries, {prepare: true}, function(err){
    if(err){
        //api responds here with error
    } else {
        //api responds here with success
    }
});
```

Comment: Your understanding of consistency is correct. Could you elaborate on your queries and how the results are inconsistent? One common gotcha is query timestamps, which can cause updates to be applied in a different order than expected. Are your server clocks sync'd?

Comment: The server times are synced. Adding an example to the question of how I am querying, what I am expecting, and what I appear to be receiving.

Comment: It's interesting, I thought the PK on username was just the username but it includes the ID. It looks like there is a possibility the users table is just not being deleted correctly on account deletion. This is done in a batch query similar to the insertion. Investigating.

Comment: Turns out there is not an inconsistency in the database, there is an inconsistency in the data due to a partially failed deletion batch query successfully deleting from the username table but not from the users table, should be resolved with a retry

Comment: Wasn't solved with the retry, I resynced the clocks and now cannot reproduce the problem, so this was likely the issue.

Comment: You can also pass timestamps from the client instead of letting the server generate them. Add a [QueryOptions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/nodejs/3.0/global.html#QueryOptions) to the execute call and set its `timestamp` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the clocks on my cassandra servers were not synced.